# Android SQL - Using a cursor to select a value error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am struggling with some SQLite stuff. Pretty much, 'value' is a string value that contains the column I want to select in 'CompletedRow'. When I set the value of 'status' (a textview) to the cursor, it returns the text 'CompletedRow'. This is my code:

```
Cursor indexCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT 'CompletedRow' FROM MyChallenges WHERE ChalName = '" + value + "';", null);
indexCursor.moveToFirst();
String val = indexCursor.getString(0);
status.setText(val);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `' '` from ColumnName `CompletedRow` and i think `ChalName` has datatype String so no need to use `ChalName = '" + value + "'` Use `ChalName = " + value` instead it.

Try this

```
Cursor indexCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT CompletedRow FROM MyChallenges WHERE ChalName = " + value , null);
```

Comment: i think for this littele you mention it on commnet and plz write chnges that you done so op easily understand this

Answer (score 2):

If the name of your field is CompletedRow change the query to:

```
Cursor indexCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT CompletedRow FROM MyChallenges WHERE ChalName = " + value , null);
```

More info: [SQLite SELECT Statement](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/select/)

Changes  insted of 'CompletedRow' change CompletedRow meas remove ' '

Comment: i think for this littele you mention it on commnet and plz write chnges that you done so op easily understand this